# EF Core can't pass value type via aggregate constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

## The problem

I have the need to initialise a new domain entity that accepts a basic value object via its constructor. The persistence mechanism behind the domain is SQL server driven by Entity Framework Core.

The issue I have is that when EF Core tries to create the database schema it can't associate the value object parameter with any mapped property.

What am I missing here? Any help would be much appreciated.

## My simplified domain model

```
public sealed class Address
{
    public string StreetAddress { get; }

    public string Town { get; }

    public string PostalCode { get; }

    internal Address(string streetAddress, string town, string postalCode)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public sealed class PropertyListing
{
    public Guid Id { get; }

    public string Title { get; }

    public string Description { get; }

    public Address Address { get; }

    public decimal GuidePrice { get; }

    internal PropertyListing(Guid id, string title, string description, Address address, decimal guidePrice)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

## My database model configuration

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyListing>(builder =>
        {
            builder.HasKey(model => model.Id);

            builder.Property(model => model.Title).IsRequired();

            builder.Property(model => model.Description).IsRequired();

            builder.Property(model => model.GuidePrice).IsRequired();

            builder.OwnsOne(model => model.Address, address =>
            {
                address.Property(model => model.StreetAddress).IsRequired();

                address.Property(model => model.Town).IsRequired();

                address.Property(model => model.PostalCode).IsRequired();
            });
        });
    }
```

## The results

When it comes time to create the database schema, Entity Framework throws the following exception:

> **System.InvalidOperationException**: 'No suitable constructor found for entity type '**PropertyListing**'. The following parameters could not be bound to properties of the entity: '**address**'.'

## My technology stack

- **Entity Framework Core** 2.1.0-preview1-final
- **ASP.NET Core** 2.0

## Reference materials

- [Entity types with constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors)
- [Owned entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)
- [Allow related entities to be passed to constructor of aggregate root](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12078)

Comment: Can you try with adding default constructor internal `PropertyListing()
    {
        ...
    }`

Comment: The third link is pointing to an *open* issue in EF Core, hence apparently you are hitting a current EF Core limitation.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes I realised the issue was open but I just wondered if I had missed something in the issue's discussion

Comment: Adding a default constructor as suggested by @viveknuna seemed to work in my  case.  Not sure why though.